# LimeSurvey email confirmation

Tags: email, limesurvey

How can I send automatic email confirmation? I have an email field in the survey, I would like to send Confirmations email to that address aftre completing the survey.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a basic or detailed notification. Refer to the [LimeSurvey manual](http://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_settings#Notification_.26_data_management).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry for lateness answer.

If you use Limesurvey version 3+ you can put SGQ code (S of survey G of group and Q of question number) into a {INSERTANS:SSSSSXGGGXQQQ} instead of mail recipient.

Comment: dear Garnet 023  -- thx for this reply  - is this a token based answer. In other words. Do you prefer to send a token- i love to hear from you again!